# django logout using a link or form to prevent csrf exploit

Tags: django, csrf, logout

while reading up [djangobook chapter](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter16/) ,I came across the section which mentions a csrf exploit where a logout link was put in a hidden  of malicious site.

In a web app I created using django,I had used a similar logout link

base.html:

```
<a  href="{% url my_logout %}" > Logout </a>
```

where the my_logout url points to `django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login`

```
urlpatterns=patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
url(r'^logout/$', 'logout_then_login', {}, name = 'my_logout'),
)
```

Now,after reading about csrf attack,I fear that a malicious site can cause trouble for me too.So,I would like to use a form to do the logging out.

I thought I could do like this

base.html:

```
    ...

    <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="true" />
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
...
```

Now,how should I write the view for processing this form?If I am to process the hidden variables(`confirm` to check whether logout should be done and `next` to go to the previous view) ,will I  still be able to use the `django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login` method?

can someone please tell me if I am doing this the right way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap it like

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@csrf_protect
@require_POST
@never_cache
def safer_logout(request):
    # 'confirm' is useless here, POST implies 'do it'
    return logout_then_login(request, request.POST.get('next'))
```

Also, consider using  [SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-httponly)

Comment: @ClaudeVedovini just felt somebody was typing fast when I was editing it, ha =p

Comment: I was going to post almost the same answer :) 

Anyway, I would add that I don't think this is really useful. CSRF exploits are used to trick users in completing actions in applications they are logged in, there is not really a point in forcing them to logout.

Comment: @ClaudeVedovini Yes, but sometimes its harmful when the attacker intends to log you out for a while or wait for your new login procedure

Comment: thanks guys..a small problem though.. the next parameter returns emptystring no matter where I logout from .wont it get set automatically in the form?

Comment: what about not to pass in request.POST.get('next')