# Django state change to prevent csrf example

Tags: django

My template at the top contains a link to perform different functions - save, login, logout..etc...I'm able to control the flow to make sure the state does not change when the request is a GET method.

But, for logout I'm not sure how to prevent the state change..ie; it should not logoff when the link `/logout` is typed.

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="/">home</a> |
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="/save/">submit</a>
        <a href="/search/">search</a>
        <a href="/user/{{ user.username}}">{{user.username}}</a>
        <a href="/logout/">logout</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/login/">login</a>
        <a href="/register/">Register</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**urls.py**

```
(r'^logout/$',logout_page),
```

Comment: You mean you want to prevent logout request, when the user is already logged out..?

Comment: Want to prevent the Cxrf attack?.. The logout should happen without knowing to the user

Comment: Can you just use form input instead of a logout link?

Comment: How so I do that? Examples pls

Comment: Just follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930068/django-logout-using-a-link-or-form-to-prevent-csrf-exploit).